# Why is WebView acting different from Safari (private browsing)?

Tags: macos, cocoa, redirect, cookies, webview

I am trying to login to instagram and approve my app within my OS X app by opening a web view within my OS X app. I've tried both deleting all cookies *and* using private browsing independently from each other. I don't intercept requests/responses. First, when I try to open auth URL, I get the following (and correct) page both in my app and in Safari:

[image]

However, when I enter my username and password, if Safari, my Instagram account opens, redirects to the app correctly e.g. it logs in. When I enter my (obviously, the same) credentials in my app and click Log in, I'm transferred back to the same screen in a redirect loop of about 10 times:

`https://instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login=&next=/oauth/authorize/%3Fclient_id%3DMY_CLIENT_ID_REMOVED_FOR_SECURITY%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%3A//my.redirect.url.removed.for.security%26response_type%3Dcode`

If I try to visit that URL in Safari, I get to the login screen (if not logged in), and I get redirected to the correct URL afterwards.

I've tried entering invalid credentials, I'm getting a different error, so it's not an incorrect username/password issue:

[image]

It appears like a cookies/redirection issue. I've removed all delegates just in case they are intercepting with the login mechanism, but no avail.

Why can't I login to Instagram on Cocoa web view while I perfectly can in Safari? I'm on the latest OS X 10.11.1 and Safari 9.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was apparently a bug with Instagram's own cookies, which required a cookie storage reset *inside the app's cookie container*, which I forgot to clear (I cleared Safari's, but it's different from the app's container).

I've added an option to clear cookies on app startup:

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *jar = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
NSArray *cookies = jar.cookies;
for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) {
    [jar deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

I've invoked this code and the problem went away.